# How to change values while looping through an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I keep getting stuck on this issue and have done a lot of searching/reading to try to understand the problem, but I just don't get it. Am wondering if someone can provide me with an example of how to update object values while looping an IEnumerable<>.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IEnumerable<MyData> _MyData = null;

    public MyClass() {}
    public MyClass(string parm1, int parm2) { Load(parm1, parm2); }

    public IEnumerable<MyData> Load(string parm1, int parm2)
    {
        _MyData = _dbContext.MyData.Where(m => m.Parm1 == parm1 && m.Parm2 == parm2);

        foreach(MyData mydata in _MyData)
        {
            if(mydata.Parm2 == 1)
            {
                mydata.Parm1 = "Some value";
            }
        }
        return _MyData;
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work as any changes made to `mydata.Parm1` within the loop are not retained. I read an SO article that suggested to make changes like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _MyData.Count(); i++)
{
    _MyData.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault().Parm1 = "Some Value";
}
```

This works, but it's really ugly and hard for me to believe there isn't a cleaner way. For a single change it might be acceptable, but I have several changes that need to be made. So I've attempted this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _MyData.Count(); i++)
{
    MyData md = _MyData.ElementAt(i);
    md.Parm1 = "Some Value";
}
```

But I don't understand how to put the modified `md` back into _MyData to save changes.

I think the main reason I'm going through all of these hoops is that I don't understand how to make changes to the elements and have them retained. Any changes I make seem to revert back to their original values unless I go through these hoops. Maybe someone can point out where I'm going wrong. I would like to use this class like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyData> MyDataResult = new MyClass("Parm1", 4);
```

Using the above line of code, I can trace through the `Load()` function and see that the desired changes are being made, but once finished `MyDataResult` contains the original values instead of those I saw being changed.

It is more then obvious that my code is wrong, but I hope I've been clear enough to illustrate what I'm wanting to do and where I'm having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are returning a value which never gets used. You just need to set `_MyData` in your `Load` method as it is a class level variable.
Change Load to not return a value and `ToList()` your query on the db context and then set your `_MyData` to your concrete list object in Load.

Something like this will work - I've simplified your example slightly but same principals:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<string> _MyData = null;
    public IEnumerable<string> _dbContext = new List<string> {"a", "b", "aa", "bb"};
    public MyClass(){}
    public MyClass(string parm1, int parm2){Load(parm1, parm2);}

    public void Load(string parm1, int parm2)
    {
        var somedata = _dbContext.Where(m => m.Length == 2).ToList();

        var myData = somedata.Select(s => s == parm1 ? "something else" : s).ToList();

        _MyData = myData;
    }
}
```

Use can use

```
var a = new MyClass("aa",1)._MyData;
```

and "aa" will get replaced with "something else" and be returned to "a".

You can't use a class like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyData> MyDataResult = new MyClass("Parm1", 4);
```

If you ask for an `MyClass` you'll get a `MyClass` not an `IEnumerable`.

If your call to dbContext is to an underlying data source you may be better off not doing that in the class constructor and always call Load explicitly following class construction. You then have options to avoid thread blocking on a potentially long running I/O operation.

Comment: You're right, but I also use the class without passing parameters on instantiation. In that case I am forced to call `MyClass.Load()` on my own and want to return the data in that case.

Comment: I think you need a MyData public property and use _MyData as its private backing field. Load() is an instance member of your class as is MyData so Load() does not need to return anything. MyData just needs to be accessible. If Load was static then that's different.

Comment: I too your suggestion to create a method that returns _MyData and for the first time I am seeing the modified values after instantiation instead of the originals. Now there's a different problem in that the returned _MyData is indexed where I have to specify `MyData[nn].Parm1` to reference each element. Previously I was able to do just `MyData.Parm1`. Sorry about the ignorance here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
_MyData = _dbContext.MyData.Where(m => m.Parm1 == parm1 && m.Parm2 == parm2).ToList();
```

To be clear, essentially what you have in your current code is a query, which you are enumerating in your Load method, trying to update some of its properties, but then in the end, you end up returning the **query**, and not the updated values in the query.

The caller of `Load` method, will end up running the query a second time, only to see direct values from the database.

Adding `.ToList` to the end of the query in `Load` method, **materializes** the query, and then you are doing rest of the operations in memory.

**EDIT:**
Just in case, if there would be performance concern over the large amount of data this query may return, then you could also consider this alternate approach -

```
public IEnumerable<MyData> Load(string parm1, int parm2)
{
    _MyData = _dbContext.MyData.Where(m => m.Parm1 == parm1 && m.Parm2 == parm2);

    foreach(MyData mydata in _MyData)
    {
        if(mydata.Parm2 == 1)
        {
            mydata.Parm1 = "Some value";
        }

        yield return myData;
    }
}
```

This would keep the query lazy, and still return the modified values, as caller of `Load` iterates over the `IEnumerable<MyData>` returned by `Load`.

Comment: Vikas, that does clarify things better for me. I'm trying .ToList() now. Will materializing the query as you suggest allow me to do away with `.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault()...` and allow me to change values directly? Ie: `_MyData.Parm1 = "Some value";`?

Comment: @rwkiii `.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault()...`  just doesn't make sense to me (I do understand the code, but I don't see any way, why one would write such code in current context).. It's most inefficient way of writing code which can be simple.. Someone seems to be confusing it with the problem of "not being able to modify the *collection* while you are iterating over it with a `foreach`". You are **not** modifying the collection, your are updating properties of values in collection. and AFAIK, above code should do it for you (Unless you have performance concerns due to query results being too large).

Comment: I'm really glad to hear you state this. It was a popular answer and a lot of upvotes so I used it - but I didn't like it at all. I think the only reason it was suggested was because the poster was using IEnumerable and having the same problem I am. Using your answer I am still having a problem with the values reverting to their originals after the class is finished instantiating - even though I can see _MyData containing the changed values on the very last line of Load().